# Split SQL Where IN Clause When List is to big into Smaller Requests in Python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, aws-lambda, aws-aurora-serverless, aws-data-wrangler

I have setup an AWS Lambda function with python to ingest requests from a CSV and then query an AWS Serverless Aurora PostgreSQL database based on this request. The function works when the requests are less then 1K but I get errors due to a hard limit in the data API. I am trying to figure out a way to break up the query into smaller queries once this limit is hit but not sure how to do this in python. Can someone suggest a way to break up a request into smaller chunks so I do not hit the data API limit?

Snippet of Code Used:

```
#Set Database connection params
engine = wr.data_api.rds.connect( resource_arn = resource_arn, database=database_name, secret_arn=secret_arn)

#read in s3 csv and select ids
read_df = wr.s3.read_csv(path=s3_path_in)
requested_ids = read_df["ids"]
in_ID = requested_ids.tolist()
in_query= str(tuple(in_ID))

#query postgres
query_id = """
select c.*
from table1 b
INNER JOIN table2 c on b.id = c.id
where b.id in %s
""" % in_query

out_ids = wr.data_api.rds.read_sql_query(query_id, engine)
```

Comment: Populate some kind of temp table first?

Comment: Split your list of IDs into smaller batches. Loop through each batch and execute the query. Merge all the results.

Answer (score 0):

one way that i can think of is to use the `LIMIT <row_count>` clause of the postgres SQL and dynamically pass the `row_count` to your query  .

```
select c.*
from table1 b
INNER JOIN table2 c on b.id = c.id
where b.id in <>
order by <primary_key>
limit 999
```

[PostgreSQL LIMIT](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-limit/)

Comment: I am confused on how this will ensure all of the data is returned? It will return 999 of the entries but what about anything above 999?

Comment: take the `count of all the rows` first, and programatically derive the `row_count` till the total number of rows returned. I know it sounds to naive, but worth a try.

Comment: Does it help @Prof.Falken ?